# Stand-alone custom registry of WebSphere 6.1

Tags: websphere

WAS 6.1 of RSA 7.0 (WindowsXP)
I have a secure servlet and I want to use my database/table to verify user id and password, but when I open WAS admin console and enable security and choose Stand-alone custom registry,
"Primary administrative user name field" what value should I fill?

I try to input some such as id of was admin console, database user id and WindowsXP account, but always got error message says admin id not found in the user registry...

Answer (score 1):

You must create an administrative user in your custom user repository (in your case this is your database/table you store users), and then configure this user using administrative console. Error message is telling that user you are configuring is not found in the user registry, so you shall insert it into registry as above.

Comment: But I try to input id which is already in my table, there's still same error message...

Comment: To make sure you're using correct repository, what is the value you use in Custom registry class name field?

Comment: After I completed all function of registry class, there's no more problem! Thx

Answer (score 1):

You have to develop Custom User Registry class: [details here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_tbucs.html)

Alternatively, you can use Federated Database User Registry: [details here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0701_ilechko/0701_ilechko.html)

Comment: Can I combine local system and my database/table in the "Federated Database"?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple repositories. That's what 'federated repository' is about, actually.

Comment: Is there any step-by-step sample about Federated Database to show how to combine local system and stand-along custom registry?